# indentation of enumitem after number to match specific format

Tags: spacing, indentation, enumitem

I'm required to produce a document containing a list of items in a very specific format.  To do this, I need to use the enumitem package, but I need to specify some level of indentation AFTER the item is initialized in the enumerate environment.  Is there any way to add additional indentation after specifying an item?  I was thinking something like changing a variable defining default indentation.

```
\textbf{REFERENCES}
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=3em, leftmargin=12pt]
\item \setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}TEST OF REFERENCE TEXT AND STUFF WHICH IS MULTI-LINE IN NATURE \setlength{\leftmargin}{12pt}
\item MORE REFERENCE TEXT
\end{enumerate}
```

I end up getting something very different from what I need.

I need something that has the number on the left, but the text taken at a space:

Example:

> 1._____Text starts here and indentation remains on next line
>
> 2._____Second item in list

with a specified spacing before the text starts and the number always aligned with the left margin.  Note that I can't just insert a `\hspace` since the text will be multi-line in nature and would have to be applied to both lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Some text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text.
\begin{enumerate}[align = left,labelwidth =* ,labelsep*=-1pt,itemindent = 0pt, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep\relax, ]
\item Text starts here and indentation remains on next line. Text starts here and indentation remains on next line.
\item Second item in list
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Although I modify the leftmargin argument to suit the specific requirement (I have a set length to conform to).  Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the `label indent`? I supposed you wanted the distance between end of label and beginning of text to be 12pt? Are there other requirements?

Comment: Essentially I wanted the number to be aligned with the preceding paragraphs and a defined distance for where the text started.  That was the main requirement.

Comment: Is my updated answer what you want?

Comment: not quite... the numbers would be aligned with the start of "more" on the second line of "some more text"

Comment: So the first version was what you want? See the updated answer (The vertical lines correspond to the `showframe` option of `geometry, to show left and right margins for the text.

Comment: Yep, that works.  The amount of space after the number is what I needed to control.